# Enabling Resource Aggregation with Bootstrap 3

Tags: xpages

I'm using Bootstrap files within my application and I want to enable "Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources".

[image]

the problem I have is once enabled; glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot, glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg and glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff cannot be found:

[image]

I know for Bootstrap 2.3 we could use a Theme that loads a .CSS file that changes relative locations as described here http://www.bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/site.nsf/article.xsp?documentId=F435B6DC54486B67C1257B6B002E5A6C&action=openDocument

So, what should I do to handle relative locations with Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tweak the path to the web font resoureces in the Bootstrap CSS files.
Delete the part with "../" and replace it with the relative path to the font files within your project structure, e.g.

bootstrap/fonts/...

Then aggregation will load the fonts correctly.

Comment: I created a copy of bootstrap.min.css and there I replaced "../" for bootstrap/fonts. Also I modified my Theme to load bootstrap.min.css if context.getProperty('xsp.resources.aggregate').equals('false') otherwise I load my new bootstrap.aggregation.min.css

Answer (score 4):

This does not answer your question but if you want to use Bootstrap 3 you'd be MUCH better off using the Boostrap4Xpages project on OpenNTF.org.  It will perform better and the resource aggregation will work better.  It's easy to install and use but it is a plugin on the sever so  that needs to be done.  It's not self contained to the NSF. Try and move to this if at all possible.

Regarding the actual question.  I'm not sure I know the answer specifically.  I do know that using relative links can sometimes be a problem if the browser's URL doesn't have the page.xsp portion.  So it works on the page.xsp and NOT the default launch XPage where the URL ends with the database.nsf.  What I've done in the past there is set the application to launch to something like "start.xsp" and in that page in beforePageLoad to a redirect to "home.xsp".  This forces the browser url to always show the page name and made life a little easier when dealing with adding projects to WebContent.

Comment: thanks for the info. I'll consider it on my next project; this one is on UAT and I'm looking for performance improvements. Glad you mentioned the Launch option from DB Properties; I had this issue and I had to modify my code a little bit.

Comment: The redirect technique David mentions here is also an excellent place to change the used theme or other application/client-type environment setup.

Comment: Can you expand on that Keith?  I'm not sure what that means.  Thanks